# Hide function arguments (from unknown functions) for simpler output

Tags: output-formatting

How can I print my expression with my function's arguments hidden?

For example:

```
exp=A[r,z]+B[s]^2;

HideArgs[exp]
```

Output:

```
A+B^2
```

The expression that could be tested is this one:

```
r^3*(Br[r, z]^2+Bz[r, z]^2)==E^(6\[Psi][r, z])*(r*D[\[Psi][r, z], z, z]+r*D[\[Psi][r, z],r,r])
```

Where the unknown functions are:

```
Br[r,z],Bz[r,z],\[Psi][r, z]
```

Comment: What do you want as output of `exp=Sin[A[r,z]+B[s]^2]`?

Comment: Just for my unknow functions, so I want it as:     exp=Sin[A+B^2]

Answer (score 3):

Here is another crude way but it seems flexible.

```
funcs = {Plus, Times, Power, Sin, Equal};
SetAttributes[HideArgs, HoldAll];
HideArgs[expr_] :=  expr /. {x_[__] /; And @@ (UnsameQ[x, #] & /@ funcs) :> x}
```

You can continue to add functions to `funcs` that shouldn't have their arguments hidden.
 For your example:

```
HideArgs[A[r, z] + B[s]^2]
```

Gives:

```
A + B^2
```

Also:

```
HideArgs[A[r, z]]
```

Gives:

```
A
```

Finally:

```
HideArgs[Sin[A[r, z] + B[s]^2]]
```

Gives:

```
Sin[A + B^2]
```

To test your real equation, I've added `Equal` to `funcs`:

```
HideArgs[r^3*(Br[r, z]^2 + Bz[r, z]^2) == E^(6 \[Psi][r, z])*(r*D[\[Psi][r, z], z, z] +
r*D[\[Psi][r, z], r, r])]
```

Gives:

```
(Br^2 + Bz^2)*r^3 == E^(6*\[Psi])*(r*Derivative[0, 2][\[Psi]] + r*Derivative[2, 0][\[Psi]])
```

Comment: Is there a function that returns a list of all known functions in MMA?

Comment: @s0rce, I guess ``Names["System`*"]``

Comment: Hrmm, why doesn't replacing `funcs` with `Names["System\`*"]` work?

Comment: @s0rce, I think that expression not only includes the MMA functions but the ones you've defined so it's probably not a good idea to use.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for polynomials but is a bit messy:

```
HideArgs[exp_] := With[{exp2 = exp + 0[_]}, Replace[exp2, #[__] -> # & /@ Variables[exp2][[All, 0]], \[Infinity]]]

HideArgs[A[r,z]+B[s]^2]
```

> A + B^2

```
HideArgs[A[r, z]]
```

> A

There might be a cleaner way.

Comment: Thanks sOrce, it's this what I want, but it fails to work for example on HideArgs[A[r,z]]

Comment: Fixed but pretty crude, must be a better way.