# How to hide arguments of a function in traditional output?

Tags: output-formatting

There are some interesting suggestions concerning how to hide function's arguments in output
([Hide function arguments (from unknown functions) for simpler output](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40298/hide-function-arguments-from-unknown-functions-for-simpler-output))
and how to make traditional output for derivatives
([How to make traditional output for derivatives](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/how-to-make-traditional-output-for-derivatives))
It would be great to combine these two possibilities within one document. But it appears that hiding of arguments doesn't work in traditional output while in the same time it's hardly possible to obtain normal form of derivatives in standard output. So I'll be very grateful if anyone posts suggestions how to hide arguments in traditional output.

Comment: Can you give a clear and simple example of what output you would like to have?

Comment: For example, instead of standard output generated from D[f[x,y,z],x] I'd like to see something like that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

Comment: @Teo, so what is wrong with suggestion from reference questions? `f /: Format[f[___]] := f; Defer@D[f[x, y, z], x] // TraditionalForm`

Comment: Related: [15153](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15153/simplify-function-notation)